# Dreaded by many; loved by few

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Dreaded by many, loved by few.

> Even the most ardent can break over my weight,
> Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.
>
> Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.
> Look towards your friends, they may convey.
>
> Eaten little by little am I, line by line,
> So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.
>
> Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

What am I?

Comment: Haha I love the acrostic here; especially when coupled with the answer by @El-Guest!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> HOMEWORK?

Even the most ardent can break over my weight,

> Lots of homework can be difficult for even hard workers to do well at.

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> You probably hate homework.

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> If you get behind, it's difficult to catch up with your homework

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Your friends can help you with various study groups

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,

> Every day is one day closer to the end of the homework, you have to do it line by line

So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> You have to ensure that it's done correctly

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> After lots of homework, you'll have a better understanding of the things you study. You'll also have much improved time management.

The title:

> Most people don't enjoy homework, although some do.

Secret hints:

> The acrostic is ENDLESS, which can be how a lot of courses and homework feels (especially by the 3 month period, speaking from experience!!)

Comment: It's a teensy more specific than this, just a smidgen. It's something you do outside of class.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know how does this revision look?

Comment: :D You've got it!

Comment: Yay!! Haha this one hit a little close to home, @Joe-You-Know ;P

Comment: I know... My engineering courses are killers...

Comment: Oof. This makes more sense. Didn't look at this answer before I posted mine XD

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> Exercise or a treadmill

Even the most ardent can break over my weight

> Heavy weights.

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> People don't like exercise.

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> If you don't run on a tread mill you will fall. Also a treadmill is infinite which is the acrostic.

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Encouragement?

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,
So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> You can trip on a treadmill.

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> Exercise is hard.

Comment: Nice one! I see your trigger finger is still quite sharp! :D Love this answer too!!

Comment: lol thanks, @El-Guest nice answer back at you! :D

Comment: Haha, this answer is great, though not quite what I intended.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> School/University?

Even the most ardent can break over my weight,

> It's difficult to keep doing well in school

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> Lots of people hate it

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> If you get behind, it's difficult to catch up in classes

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Your friends can help you during school

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,

> Every day is one day closer to the end

So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> You have to find the right career path, and do well on exams

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> After the time in school, you'll have a better understanding of the things you study

The title:

> School is dreaded by many and loved by few

Secret hints:

> The acrostic is ENDLESS, which can be how school feels

Comment: You're thinking along the right paths, though I was thinking something a little more specific than this. The answer is related to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [El-Guest's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72845/dreaded-by-many-loved-by-few/72849#72849)

Are you

> Math

Even the most ardent can break over my weight,
Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> Some people don't like math.

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.
Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> If you don't learn simple math the later stuff will be super hard and you may ask your friends for help.

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,

> Take it slow.

So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> Positive or negative sign!

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> Your logic will improve.

Title

> I love math(like love), but some else might not.

Acrostic

> Infinity, endless graphs, and so much more is endless in math.

Comment: You know, I can see why you got this answer. This time, it's a little too specific.

Answer (score 3):

Similar answers, but nobody's suggested this one yet. Are you

> Studying

Even the most ardent can break over my weight

> Studying can be an immense burden for even good students.

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> People don't like studying.

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> If you fall behind on studying it can be hard to catch up, as new materials and tests keep coming.

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Study buddies.

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,
So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> You read one line at a time, and make sure you've understood it as you go.

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> You need to study to understand a course.

Acrostic:

> You never really stop studying/learning.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Knowledge

Even the most ardent can break over my weight

> The amount of information and knowledge that is accessible can be unfathomable

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> You only hate what you know of

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> Falling behind in knowledge and learning can prevent you from being up to date on the latest trends/technologies/discoveries/etc.

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Your friends may have the knowledge you seek, especially in a specialized world

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,
So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> Very easy to misunderstand something or misinterpret it

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> Learning something new can be tough, but rewarding at the end

Acrostic:

> Never stop learning!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are

> Knowledge

Even the most ardent can break over my weight

> Knowing too much can sometimes lead to bad consequences *insert Godfather reference here*

Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> For gaining knowledge you need to learn. To learn you must study. Very few people like to study purely for the sake of it.

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.

> If you fail to keep up to date with the latest information you will be considered as outdated hence fall behind and get "swept away" with the new trends in technology and other such stuff

Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> Even your friends can teach you things you may not know. Even they can give you knowledge about stuff you have not experienced but they have.

Eaten little by little am I, line by line, So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> You learn little by little. You cannot suddenly gain full knowledge about a matter over a night but through experiences and studying. So that you may not fall into trouble due to lack of knowledge

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> This is kinda self explanatory. While the process of gaining knowledge may be hard and make you suffer, it will ultimately help you in the long run.

Also the accrostic

> ENDLESS. Knowledge is endless.

Answer (score 1):

Your are

> this riddle itself

Even the most ardent can break over my weight,
Not that you've noticed since it's me that you hate.

> It's a hard riddle and you start to hate what you can't solve

Don't get behind now, lest you're swept away.
Look towards your friends, they may convey.

> look to new solutions, your friends may see the solution before you do by observing you

Eaten little by little am I, line by line,
So that you may not trip up and find the right sign.

> seeing the acrostic "endless"

Suffer me a little while, so you can be brought to a full understanding of things.

> the longer you have to think about this riddle, the more it becomes the solution (endless, hating it, breaking under its weight)

acrostic

> since the solution is the riddle itself, it has no real solution / it is circular

Even if it isn't the real solution I liked the idea and maybe someone wants to make a riddle matching it.